# Simple function-size; Understanding pointer-pointer difference

Tags: c++, function, pointers, memory-address

I'm testing some ways of calculating the size,in bytes of a function(I'm familiar with opcodes on x86). The code is quite self-explanatory:

```
void exec(void* addr){
    int (WINAPI *msg)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT)=(int(WINAPI *)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT))addr;

    msg(0,"content","title",0);
}
void dump(){};

int main()
{

    cout<<(char*)dump-(char*)exec;  // this is 53
    return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to substract the address of 'exec' from 'dump'. This works but I noticed the values differ when using other types of pointers like DWORD*:

```
void exec(void* addr){
    int (WINAPI *msg)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT)=(int(WINAPI *)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT))addr;

    msg(0,"content","title",0);
}
void dump(){};

int main()
{
    cout<<(DWORD*)dump-(DWORD*)exec;  // this is 13
    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding no matter the pointer type ,it is always the largest possible data type(so that it can handle large adresses),in my case of 4 bytes (x86 system). The only thing that changes between pointers is the data type it points to.

What is the explanation?

Comment: `cout<<(char*)dump-(char*)exec;`  in C, the `<<` operator does notaccept pointers as operands. Maybe you are using C++?

Comment: subtraction of pointers to two unrelated things is meaningless in C++

Comment: Note that the compiler can put functions in any order in the output file; this subtraction might not give you the result you expect.

Comment: @wildplasser: `(char*)dump` is a pointer (if the cast is accepted). `(char*)dump-(char*)exec` is an integer of type `ptrdiff_t`. (BTW, the `<<` does accept pointers as operands. A character pointer is treated as a pointer to a string; other pointers are printed in some implementation-defined way, similar to C's `printf("%p", ptr)`).

Comment: @KeithThompson  oops. You're right, of course.

Comment: In any case, the results you see are likely to have nothing to do with "function size". In general case this method will not allow you to determine function size. Functions have no size. What you get is the distance between the entry points, which might not be correlated to the function size at all.

Comment: @AnT: Well, he's getting 53, which is quite plausibly the size in bytes of the generated code for the `exec` function. But the technique is horribly non-portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic in C/C++ is designed for accessing elements of an array. In fact, array indexing is merely a simpler syntax for pointer arithmetic. For example, if you have an array named `array`, `array[1]` is the same thing as `*(array+1)`, regardless of the data type of the elements in `array`.

(I'm assuming here that no operator overloading is going on; that could change everything.)

If you have a `char*` or `unsigned char*`, the pointer points to a single byte, and incrementing the pointer advances it to the next byte.

In Windows, `DWORD` is a 32-bit value (four bytes), and `DWORD*` points to a 32-bit value. If you increment a `DWORD*`, the pointer is advanced by *four bytes*, just as `array[1]` gives you the second element of the array, which is four bytes (one `DWORD`) after the first element. Similarly, if you add 10 to a `DWORD*`, it advances 40 bytes, not 10 bytes.

Either way, incrementing or adding to a pointer is only valid if the resulting pointer points into the same array as the original one, or one element past the end. Otherwise it is undefined behavior.

Pointer subtraction works just like addition. When you subtract one pointer from another, they must be the same type, and must be pointers into the same array or one past the end.

What you're doing is counting the number of elements between the two pointers, as if they were pointers into the same array (or one past the end). But when the two pointers *don't* point into the same array (or again, one past the end), the result is undefined behavior.

Here is a reference from Carnegie Mellon University about this:

[ARR36-C. Do not subtract or compare two pointers that do not refer to the same array - SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/ARR36-C.+Do+not+subtract+or+compare+two+pointers+that+do+not+refer+to+the+same+array)

Comment: Not just the same type.  [expr.add]/6 states: *Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or
one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: Yup, I wrote it unclearly the first time; I was editing to fix that when you wrote your comment. Thanks for keeping me on my toes!

Answer (score 1):

Pointer subtraction tells you the number of elements between the two addresses, so using DWORD * it will be in DWORD sized units.

Comment: Lets say there are 3 bytes. How would this translate to DWORD sized units?

Comment: @sergiureznicencu it is undefined behaviour if the two things being subtracted are not pointers to elements of the same array. And in an array of DWORD there can not be  2 elements separated by 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
cout<<(char*)dump-(char*)exec;
```

where `dump` and `exec` are the names of functions. Each cast converts a function pointer to `char*`.

I'm not sure about the status of such a conversion in C++. I think it either has undefined behavior or is illegal (making your program ill-formed). When I compile with g++ 4.8.4 with options `-pedantic -std=c++11`, it complains:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids casting between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
```

(There's a similar diagnostic for C, which I believe is not strictly correct, but that's another story.)

There's no guarantee that there's any meaningful relationship between object pointers and function pointers.

Apparently your compiler lets you get away with the casts, and presumably the result is a `char*` representation of the address of the function. Subtracting two pointers yields the distance between the two addresses *in units of the type the pointers point to*.  Subtracting two `char*` pointers yields a `ptrdiff_t` result that is the difference in bytes. Subtracting two `DWORD*` pointers yields the difference in unit of `sizeof (DWORD)` (probably 4 bytes?). That explains why you get different results. If two `DWORD` pointers don't point to addresses that aren't a whole number of `DWORD`s apart in memory, the results are unpredictable, but in your example getting 13 rather than 53 (truncating) is plausible.

**However**, pointer subtraction is defined only when both pointer operands point to elements of the same array object, or just past the end of it. For any other operands, the behavior is undefined.

For an implementation that permits the casts, that uses the same representation for object pointers and for function pointers, and on which the value of a function pointer refers to a memory address in the same way that the value of an object pointer does, you can likely determine the size of a function by converting its address to `char*` and subtracting the result from the converted address of an adjacent function. But a compiler and/or linker is free to generate code for functions in any order it likes, including perhaps inserting code for other functions between two functions whose definitions are adjacent in your source code.

If you want to determine the size in bytes, use pointers to byte-sized types such as `char`. And be aware that the method you're using is not portable and is not guaranteed to work.

If you really need the size of a function, see if you can get your linker to generate some kind of map showing the allocated sizes and locations of your functions. There's no portable way to do it from within C++.